# Maxlength does not work React Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an input with React, but `maxlength` does not work. Does anyone know how to solve this?

This is handleChangeInput

```
 handleChangeInput(input) {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        form: {
            ...this.state.form,
            [input.target.name]: input.target.value
        }
    })
}
```

And this is my input:

```
<div className="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
    <input onChange={this.handleChangeInput} value={this.state.form.message} type="text" className="phone validate" name="phone" maxlength="11"/>
    <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
</div>
```

[image: Code preview]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Property and attribute names are generally `camelCase` in React, `maxLength` works.

```
<input
  onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
  value={this.state.form.message}
  type="text"
  className="phone validate"
  name="phone"
  maxLength="11"
/>
```

However, you can still override this option if you give the input a `value` longer than `maxLength`. The only way around this is to check the length of the `value` in the callback, and truncate it.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { form: { message: "" } };

  handleChangeInput = event => {
    const { value, maxLength } = event.target;
    const message = value.slice(0, maxLength);

    this.setState({
      form: {
        message
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
        value={this.state.form.message}
        type="text"
        className="phone validate"
        name="phone"
        maxLength="11"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use maxLength as bedCase but it did not work either

Comment: This is the proper way to do it, I've tested the same example and works like a charm.

Comment: no need handler, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text

Answer (score 50):

for maxLength to work, type has to be 'text' (most people are probably putting number)

Comment: Then, how would you restrict it no `Numbers Only` ?

Comment: By using `type="number"` and without setting a maxlength. but keep in mind that some people like to enter phone numbers with `+` at the beginning: or enter spaces to have better readability for a number. Or even use `/` to separate caller prefix and main number (or whatever it's called in english). So: Phone numbers are complicated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text @ArsalanAhmedQuershi

Comment: To restrict number only you can supply a pattern attribute with regex of a number which will make it invalid if the input is of letters even it the input type is text

Answer (score 16):

You need to pass maxLength value as a **number**.

```
<input
  onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
  value={this.state.form.message}
  type="text"
  className="phone validate"
  name="phone"
  maxLength={11}
/>
```

Comment: If you are using typescript, You must have to pass the value as a number.

Answer (score 5):

```js
inputProps = {{maxLength:6}}
variant="outlined"
```

Answer (score 3):

For the people who's input type is `number`, this code will work

```
handlePhone(object) {
    if (object.target.value.length > object.target.maxLength) {
      object.target.value = object.target.value.slice(0, object.target.maxLength)
      this.setState({ phone: object.target.value });
    }
}

<input
    placeholder="Phone Number"
    onChange={this.handlePhone}
    type = "number" maxLength = "10"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do like this in your handleOnChange Function:

```
 handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.value <= 11){
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
   }
  };
```

Comment: Excellent. Simple and effective

Answer (score 1):

```
<input
    id="ZIPCode"
    className="form-control"
    type="text"
    maxLength={10} // this is the important line
></input>
```

React uses camelCased html attributes, so `maxlength` would then be `maxLength`

Comment: Add some description to explain your code.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I submitted an edit to add "React uses camelCased html attributes, so maxlength would then be maxLength" at the bottom, hopefully the edit is accepted

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using a reactstrap input, like other properties it uses (e.g. colSpan) it needs both camelCase naming and a number passing to it (e.g. maxLength={250}), rather than a string. I have found passing a string will work but React will complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

i have fix this using simple attribute.

```
<TextField
  type="text"
  pattern="[0-9]{10}"
  maxLength="10"
  label="Phone Number"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this approach did work.

```
<Input 
   placeholder=''
   type="text"
   maxLength="10"
   onInput={(e) => {
         e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    }}
    onChange={(e) => {
       const { value } = e.target;
    }}
/>
```